# How to promote two template types for arithmitic operations like builtin types do?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, arithmetic-expressions, type-promotion

If I have a generic struct/class:

```
template<typename T>
struct Container
{
    T value;
    Container(const Value& value) : value(value) { }
};
```

And I want to perform an operation on two of them:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Container<T> operator+(const Container<T>& lhs, const Container<U>& rhs)
{
    return Container<T>(lhs.value + rhs.value);
}
```

The problem is that if `lhs` is of the type `Container<int>` and `rhs` is of the type `Container<float>`, then I'll get a `Container<int>` back. But if I were to do `auto result = 2 + 2.0f`, then `result` would of of type `float`. So the behavior is inconsistent between builtin types and custom types.

So how would I take the `operator+` overload and make it return `Container<float>`, much like how C++ handles arithmetic promotion with builtin types?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as you use one of the two types of the template, you risk to induce a cast on the result of the sum. As an example, if you accidentally choose `int` as your target type, even though the sum results in a `float`, it will be cast down to the chosen type.

Anyway, starting with C++11, you con rely on the `decltype` specifier as in the example above (or at least, you can do that if `Container::T` and `Container::U` are a types for which the `+` operator is defined).

I used also the `auto` specifier as return value for the `operator+`, for it is at our disposal starting from C++14 and it's really useful indeed.

It follows the working example above mentioned:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Container
{
    T value;
    Container(const T& value) : value(value) { }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(const Container<T>& lhs, const Container<U>& rhs)
{
    return Container<decltype(lhs.value+rhs.value)>{lhs.value + rhs.value};
}

int main()
{
    Container<int> c1{1};
    Container<float> c2{0.5};
    std::cout << (c1+c2).value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. You can make it more readable with a `make_container` helper function allowing the template argument to be deduced: `return make_container(lhs.value + rhs.value);`

Comment: Is there any additional runtime costs added by the operation performed in the `decltype`? Would it be better if I stored the result in a temporary `auto` variable and just do something like `return Container<decltype(result)>(result);`?

Comment: The `decltype` is solved (thus wiped out) at compile time as well as the entire types system, so you won't have any additional runtime costs.